# Laravel sort by relation column using eager loader

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I used Sorter from laravel encore template to sort `<th class="left" style="width:16%;">{{trans('coursestudent.course name')}} {!! (new \Encore\Admin\Grid\Column\Sorter('_sort', 'course', null))->render() !!}</th>` , this will then send back the column, and type (desc, asc) to controller.
And in service i used `$course_students = CourseStudent::with(['course', 'customer'])` to get data, finally i use orderBy to sort

```
        if (!empty($request['_sort'])){
            if(!empty($request['_sort']['column']) && !empty($request['_sort']['type'])){
                $course_students =  $course_students->orderBy($request['_sort']['column'], $request['_sort']['type']);
            }
        }else{
            $course_students =  $course_students->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        };
```

`

But this code will only sort the table CourseStudent columns, i have try many way but i still dont know how to sort the others. For example: course name from course table and customer name from customer table. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: The `with()` method of Laravel's query builder doesn't use any kind of `JOIN ...` SQL syntax, so if you try to order by columns on either `courses` or `customers`, your SQL statement will fail due to an *"Unknown Column `courses.example`"*. Kris' answer below is correct in that you'd need to use `->leftJoin()` (or another appropriate `->join()` method). You can still use `->with(['course', 'customer'])` to eager load the related Models as `->courses` and `->customer` respectively, which is why their answer also includes `->select('course_students.*')` 

Answer (score 1):

you have to join the tables you want to order by, something like this:

```php
$course_students->leftJoin('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_students.course_id')
  ->leftJoin('students', 'students.id', '=', 'cource_students.student_id')
  ->select('course_students.*');

if (!empty($request['_sort'])){
  if(!empty($request['_sort']['column']) && !empty($request['_sort']['type'])){
    $course_students =  $course_students->orderBy($request['_sort']['column'], $request['_sort']['type']);
  }
} else {
  $course_students =  $course_students->orderBy('id', 'desc');
};
```